# How to create javadoc of a grails project

Tags: grails, javadoc

There is a way to create javadoc for a grails project?
(It makes sense?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grails doc` and look for your docs in *target/docs/api* (Java) and *target/docs/gapi* (Groovy).

Answer (score 2):

'grails-runtime-docs' plugin ( http://grails.org/plugin/grails-runtime-docs , contributed to grails by myself) is more grails aware.  It will also generate the dynamic methods and also categorize the classes into Controllers, Commands, Domains, Services and Tag Libraries.

Run:-
`grails install-plugin grails-runtime-docs` and then
`grails runtime-docs`

Comment: grails-runtime-docs fails in grails 2.2.0 with error "java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.imaginea.labs.grails.runtimedocs.GroovyRuntimeDocWriter.writePackages(GroovyRuntimeDocWriter.java:39)
 at RuntimeDocs$_run_closure4.doCall(RuntimeDocs:137)"